# Generate an image of all widgets within a scrollarea

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

BACKGROUND:
  I have a python program that is being used by a number of engineers. It indicates the status of some piece of equipment under test.

I am using a QScrollArea() to contain a QGridLayout which is packed with alot of information.

```
bit_grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
...
scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
info = QtGui.QWidget()
info.setLayout(bit_grid)
scroll.setWidget(info)
```

There are quite a few status indicators on the GUI and as such the scrollbar is used to ensure the GUI fits on one screen.

When an engineer want's to describe a failure what they are doing right now is taking multiple screenshot, one for each new displayed area of the ScrollArea. They are then stitched together to make one large image.

Is there a way to generate a png (or an img format) of the area that could be display within a ScrollArea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(scroll)
pixmap.save('path/to/file.png', None, 100)
```

This snippet will take a snapshot of whatever is inside the scrollArea and save that as a png image to `path/to/` folder as `file.png`

Comment: thanks, ill drop that into my code and try it out to see if it is relevant.

Comment: unfortunately it only captures the visible portion not the total widget content. Ill play around with this though as this does seem to be almost what is required

Comment: I solved it but ill accepted your answer as it was what sent me down the pixmap route

Answer (score 1):

ok solved.

```
    widget = self.scroll.widget()
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(widget.size())
    widget.render(pixmap)
    pixmap.save(filename, 'PNG', 100)
```

The key was to grab the widget that is in scroll as this could then be (virtually) rendered. The resultant pixmap could then be saved.